# contradictory evidence for 何に as (1) なんに and (2) なにに

Tags: kanji, pronunciation, keigo

is 何に pronounced (1) なんに or (2) なにに here: お飲み物は何になさいますか。?

(1) [www.youtube.com/watch?v=fU-hnuSM098](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fU-hnuSM098) @0:20 provides evidence (NB: despite the possibly incorrect ローマ字 (roumaji) found there and in the "show more" vocab list) "お飲み物は何になさいますか。Onomimono wa nanni nasaimasuka?"

(2) but evidence from my Japanese keyboard's programming would suggest なにに is correct because 何に doesn't pop up if I type なんに.

Finally, I thought even if it is なんに "nan ni", the mechanics of releasing the ん to transition to the articulation of に necessarily produces a sound similar to なにに

Please let me know, which is correct? (and if possible with a grammatical explanation to understand why) thank you all for your kind assistance!

Comment: another contradiction of evidence!!  A1: depends on following word 後ろに続く言葉によって読み方が異なる最たる例の１つです。それは何に対しても応用が利く

それはなににたいしてもおうようがきく

そのくらい何とでもなるさ！　

そのくらいなんとでもなるさ！と読む人が多いんじゃないかと個人的には思います。

A2: depends on required level of in/formal speech

フォーマルな感じの言葉使いなので、そういう場であれば「なににつかえますか？」と読みたいですね。 友達同士であったり、後輩や部下に対してであれば、「何に使うんだ？」と言葉自体を変えた上で、「なんにつかうんだ？」と読みたいフレーズだと思います。

Answer (score 1):

many sources indicate なにに is the preferred pronunciation of 何に in formal/polite/keigo sentences/situations and is, therefore, the preferred pronunciation in the example sentence due to its very formal/polite grammar: お飲み物は何になさいますか?